# Dependency Injection with HttpSessionStateBase and Cache in MVC 5 and Unity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, unity-container

I inherited ASP.NET MVC 5 application which has its own Context object. The context object has few static properties that returns data from `session` or `cache` object. 
For brevity purpose i have reduced the number properties to 2, one from Session and one from Cache.

```
public class MyContext
{
    public static UserVM CurrentUser
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Session.GetCurrentUserInfo();
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<StateProvinceVM> StateProvincesLookup
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Cache.GetStateProvinces();
        }
    }
}
```

**Extension methods**

```
   /// Gets the current user information. MVC version
    public static UserVM GetCurrentUserInfo(this HttpSessionStateBase session)
    {            
        // get logged-in user from the database and put it in session ( user specific)
        // and any further request for user info will be retuned from session            
    }


    // Gets the current user information. Use when we are not in MVC context        
    public static CompanyUserDTO GetCurrentUserInfo(this HttpSessionState session)
    {
        return (new HttpSessionStateWrapper(session)).GetCurrentUserInfo();
    }


    // Gets the state provinces from cahe        
    public static IEnumerable<StateProvinceVM> GetStateProvinces(this Cache cache)
    {
       // load states from database and load in Cache. (application specific)
       // any request from any user to States will be returned from Cache.
    }
```

Well this implementation is working but makes unit testing hard and also i cannot inject Session and Cache. So i refactored it as below

```
public class MyContext
{
    private static HttpSessionStateBase _session;
    private static Cache _cache;
    public TPTContext(HttpSessionStateBase session, Cache cache)
    {
        _session = session;
        _cache = cache;
    }

    public static UserVM CurrentUser
    {
        get
        {
            return _session.GetCurrentUserInfo(); 
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<StateProvinceVM> StateProvincesLookup
    {
        get
        {
            return _cache.LookupStateProvinces();
        }
    }
}
```

I am using Unity for DI. So im registering `Session` and `Cache` as

```
    container.RegisterType<HttpSessionStateBase>(new InjectionFactory(x => new HttpSessionStateWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session)));

    container.RegisterType<Cache>(new InjectionFactory(x => System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache));
```

I am not sure if my refactoring is the correct way to solve this issue.   Because i am making `_session` as static variable. Will that cause any issue down the line since session is user specific? Will it cause Captive Dependency?

I think Cache would be okay.

or this is completely anti pattern?

Comment: Neither of these should be static.

Comment: The properties are static so made private fields static.